# Nginx cache size not growing above 344GB

Tags: docker, nginx, caching, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-config

I have Nginx cache server built on Ubuntu 18 and with docker image nginx:1.19.10-alpine.

Ubuntu 18 disk usage details given below for reference

```
ubuntu@host_name:~$ df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        26G  1.4M   26G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg_system-root  193G  8.9G  176G   5% /
tmpfs                       126G     0  126G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                       126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg_data-srv      24T  369G   24T   2% /srv
/dev/sda1                   453M  364M   62M  86% /boot
overlay                     193G  8.9G  176G   5% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/64_characters_random/merged
tmpfs                        26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/1646269961
```

Docker container details

```
ubuntu@host_name:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS       PORTS     NAMES
contnr_idxyz   nginx:1.19.10-alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 days ago   Up 9 hours             contnr_name
```

Nginx Configuration for reference

```
user@host-name:/srv/mytool/nginx/config$ cat proxy.conf
access_log          off;
root                /var/log/nginx;
open_log_file_cache max=100;

log_format mytoollogformat
    '$time_iso8601 $remote_addr $status $request_time $body_bytes_sent '
    '$upstream_cache_status "$request" "$http_user_agent"';

proxy_http_version 1.1;
client_max_body_size 10g;

# R/W timeout for origin server
proxy_read_timeout 15m;
proxy_send_timeout 15m;

# R/W timeout for clients
client_body_timeout   15m;
client_header_timeout 15m;
send_timeout          15m;

# TODO: ssl_stapling and ssl_ciphers
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;

proxy_set_header Connection "";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-mytool-Cache-Host $scheme://$host;

proxy_redirect         off;

proxy_cache_path       /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=mytool:10m max_size=22000g inactive=180d;
proxy_cache_key        $host$uri$is_args$args$slice_range;
proxy_set_header       Range $slice_range;
proxy_cache_valid      200 206 2y;
proxy_cache_revalidate on;

add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_429;
```

Removed server block as it comes out of context for the current issue and also due to security reason.

Let me explain my issue in detail. We have main server(proxy_passed server) which has hundreds of TBs of file which are static resources. When we set up cache server it was filling cache and serving files from cache well. But over time noticed that cache size is not increasing above 344GB

```
user@host_name:/srv/mytool/nginx$ sudo du -sh ./*
344G    ./cache
52K     ./config
1004K   ./log
user@host_name:/srv/mytool/nginx$
```

I have wrote a script to download about 500GB's of files. But It never increased the size of cache above 344GB.
Experiments done so far
Added `max_size=100000g` (along with old value min_free=1000g)
Modified `max_size=22000g` (set less value than /srv size which is 24TB)
removed `min_free=1000g` (Assuming min_free is somehow clearing cache)
Modified
`proxy_cache_valid 200 206 1h;`  to  `proxy_cache_valid 200 206 2y;`
For all above experiments, after configuration change i have restarted docker container and ran script of downloading 500GB of files through the cache server. But even though cache size was reaching 380 to 400 GB, but within an hour it was suddenly dropping to 344GB.

I left with no clue, why cache is not filling up completely even though i have allocated 24TB for /srv

Is it issue with Nginx? I mean for free version of Nginx there might be any limitations.. Should i go with Nginx plus. Or there might be configuration mistake.

Any guess would help me. Thanks in advance

**Update**

> What are the soft and hard limits for max open files on the cache server?

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
26375980
$ ulimit -Hn
1048576
$ ulimit -Sn
1024
```

> have you set limits in your nginx conf using worker_rlimit_nofile?

Currently no settings of worker_rlimit_nofile

```
/ # cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

> Do you have anything in the error logs?

Below given filtered/distinct logs

```
$ cat /srv/mytool/nginx/log/error.log
2022/01/09 05:56:35 [warn] 22#22: *10 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/1/00/0000000001 while reading upstream, client: masked_IPv6_address, server: dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com, request: "GET /dists/58.2.A.0.409/semc/binary-arm/Packages HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[IPv6_address]:443/masked_path/Packages", host: "dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com"
2022/01/09 06:09:21 [warn] 22#22: *35 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000006, client: masked_IPv6_address, server: dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com, request: "POST /masked_path/all HTTP/1.1", host: "dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com"
2022/01/09 08:19:01 [error] 22#22: *120 etag mismatch in slice response while reading response header from upstream, client: masked_IPv6_address, server: dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com, request: "GET /masked_path/xyz.zip HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/masked_path/xyz.zip", upstream: "https://[IPv6_address]:443/masked_path/xyz.zip", host: "dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com"
2022/01/09 18:19:12 [warn] 22#22: *1566 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: masked_IPv6_address, server: dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com, request: "GET /masked_path/xyz.zip HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[masked_IPv6_address]:443/masked_path/xyz.zip", host: "dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com"
2022/01/10 01:23:20 [error] 22#22: *2920 etag mismatch in slice response while reading response header from upstream, client: masked_IPv6_address, server: dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com, request: "GET /masked_path/xyz.zip HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/masked_path/xyz.zip", upstream: "https://[IPv6_address]:443/masked_path/xyz.zip", host: "dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com"
2022/01/21 07:43:47 [error] 36#36: *441913 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: masked_IPv6_address, server: dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com, request: "GET /masked_path/xyz.zip HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[IPv6_address]:443/masked_path/xyz.zip", host: "dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com"
2022/01/21 07:46:17 [warn] 37#37: *442070 upstream server temporarily disabled while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: masked_IPv6_address, server: dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com, request: "GET /masked_path/xyz.zip HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[IPv6_address]:443/masked_path/xyz.zip", host: "dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com"

Total 25k rows same as below within 10 days of logs
2022/01/11 05:36:58 [alert] 70#70: ignore long locked inactive cache entry 55a25a5037f198bbec6cd49100bb1b76, count:1
2022/01/11 05:36:58 [alert] 70#70: ignore long locked inactive cache entry e996d5e104f405444a579cd491faf3a8, count:1
2022/01/11 05:36:58 [alert] 70#70: ignore long locked inactive cache entry 394517a8ed8e43949003b3f7538dc471, count:1
2022/01/11 05:37:08 [alert] 70#70: ignore long locked inactive cache entry 4f92d3a72f64b7bafdbb3f0b66d8e638, count:1
2022/01/11 05:37:08 [alert] 70#70: ignore long locked inactive cache entry be41b259a3e8f9698e0976639883a423, count:1
2022/01/11 05:37:08 [alert] 70#70: ignore long locked inactive cache entry 1da19b571ea4bce1428251689f0a7c69, count:1
2022/01/11 05:37:08 [alert] 70#70: ignore long locked inactive cache entry 2a4cac0c28ea430e7eef3f808cf1e06f, count:1
2022/01/11 05:37:18 [alert] 70#70: ignore long locked inactive cache entry 53a826f6931cf0f16020bcae100af347, count:1
```

**Update 2:**
Tried the same with nginx:perl docker container. It also didn't work and cache size observed that even though it grows beyond 392GB but within couple hours suddenly dropped to 344GB. Command used to start container given below

```
sudo docker run \
--detach \
--restart unless-stopped \
--volume /srv/mytool/nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro \
--volume /srv/mytool/nginx/cache:/var/cache/nginx \
--volume /srv/mytool/nginx/log:/var/log/nginx \
nginx:perl
```

**Update Again**

Avoided docker container nginx:1.19.10-alpine
And did simple Nginx configuration as given below

```
sudo apt install nginx
systemctl status nginx

$ sudo ufw app list
Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH
$ sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
```

Modify default.conf in /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=custom_cache:10m inactive=180d;

upstream origin_server {
    server dev.mytool-region.mycompany.com;
}
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://origin_server;
        }

        location ~ ^/(path1|path2|path3|path4)/ {
            slice       5m;
            proxy_cache custom_cache;

            proxy_pass http://origin_server;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 206 2y;
            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        }
}
```

Downloaded about ~500GB. It worked and cache filled as expected

```
ubuntu@host_name:/var/cache$ sudo du -sh ./*
128K    ./apparmor
82M     ./apt
4.8M    ./debconf
20K     ./ldconfig
1.2M    ./man
0       ./motd-news
518G    ./nginx
4.0K    ./pollinate
20K     ./snapd
ubuntu@host_name:/var/cache$
```

But still don't know the exact reason or what is wrong with my configuration. Still trial is going on.
**One more trial**
Used old configuration(docker nginx:1.19.10-alpine
And moved `proxy_cache_valid      200 206 2y;` inside

```
location ~ ^/(path1|path2|path3|path4)/ {
```

But this also not worked.

Comment: What are the soft and hard limits for max open files on the cache server? have you set limits in your nginx conf using worker_rlimit_nofile?

Comment: @RickRackow 

# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max --> 26375980  

# ulimit -Hn --> 1048576  

# ulimit -Sn  --> 1024    

 and
my nginx conf does not have worker_rlimit_nofile configured.

Comment: Basically we have 3 nginx cache server based on region traffic are routed through specific nginx server. In all 3 cache server same issue is observed. where server1 grows upto 369GB out of 24 TB. Server2 cache grows upto 337GB out of 10TB, and server3 grows upto 289GB out of 2.7TB

Comment: Working on an answer for you. Do you have anything in the error logs?

Comment: @TimoStark thanks, Updated answer with error logs.

Comment: Thansk @PraveenKumarLalasangi. We need more logs to find out more about the issue. Do you think it is possible to connect on discord to have a session and have a look on this?

Comment: @TimoStark thank you and i really appreciate your kindness and spirit of helping in proficient way. Now issue is resolved. Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with nginx cache slicing is when you configure cache slicing of say 5 MB.
It will end up in creating sliced cache files in cache directory.
Number of files that can be cached up is directly propotional to keys_zone size
`keys_zone=mytool:10m`
Since i had 10m(10 mega byte) for cache keys it was allowing maximum 71203 files.
Document says

> In addition, all active keys and information about data are stored in
> a shared memory zone, whose name and size are configured by the
> keys_zone parameter. One megabyte zone can store about 8 thousand
> keys.
>
> As part of commercial subscription, the shared memory zone also stores
> extended cache information, thus, it is required to specify a larger
> zone size for the same number of keys. For example, one megabyte zone
> can store about 4 thousand keys.

So modifying keys_zone to larger value `keys_zone=mytool:1000m` Fixed issue.

You can observe cache file count was not growing after 71203 for `keys_zone=mytool:10m`

```
user@host_name:/srv/mytool/nginx$ sudo du -sh ./*
326G    ./cache
52K     ./config
406M    ./log
user@host_name:/srv/mytool/nginx$ sudo find cache/ -type f | wc -l
71203
```

But it started growing in size by allowing cached file count seamlessly for `keys_zone=mytool:1000m`

```
user@host_name:/srv/mytool/nginx$ sudo du -sh ./*
518G    ./cache
52K     ./config
4.6M    ./log
user@host_name:/srv/mytool/nginx$ sudo find cache/ -type f | wc -l
107243
```

Answer (score 1):

I very suspect that your backend-services respond 'YES' when nginx asks them 'If-Modified-Since'

and your setting

```
proxy_cache_revalidate on;
```

removes outdated cache items as it supposed to do. That explains why your cache can grow up to 500G but a bit later reduces to 344G

Comment: Sounds, i should try it out. Let me come back within 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/), `max_size` parameter is optional.

> not specifying a value allows the cache to grow to use all available
> disk space.

Removing the `max-size` may let cache use all available space. Try editing the `proxy_cache_path` directive and remove it, in your current conf modified to:

`proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=mytool:10m inactive=180d;`

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried this. My initial configuration was not having max_size at all. When size was not growing i configured it to max value. That also not worked.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sorry but i need to follow some guidelines. None of the answers answered solution for my question. Even though bounty is going to waste. But no other choice it should be awarded for solution. Sorry if i failed in providing sufficient information. I will solve myself and i will write answer. Thanks again for your spirit of helping..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure the temporary cache directory

```
proxy_max_temp_file_size
```